# WS request : promise vs observable best practice

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let say I have an app with :

accident.service.ts :

```
getAccident : Observable<Accident> {
const url = 'myWSUrl';
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .map((json) => {
        return plainToClass(Accident, json);
      }).share();
}
```

accident.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.accidentService.getDepartmentsStream().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(accident => {
      this.accident = accident;
    });
```

And a view in which I display accident properties.

Is it wise to work with observable/subscribe cause as soon as I got the accident from WS, I don't need to "listen" to new events anymore. 
With a promise, as soon as I get the result, there's no more listener, but from what I've understood, with observable and subscribe, the subscribe will still be listening, which is useless cause it will not happen.
Am I right?

Comment: The idea of observable is to have multiple active listeners at different places/components/services; not necessarily the one you are showing. Promises can be triggered once and listened to once at the point of execution. If it is like an http, it is already an observable. If its an eventemitter, its already an observable. If you are sure you dont want to listen again then just do obsvblelikehttporevent.unsubscribe

Answer (score 1):

Your subscription to the observable is no more active after you unsubscribe it. (or the subscription condition is met as you have done using `takeUntil`)

Here is a detailed [post](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) by Ben Lesh about this.

Comment: Yes and in my case, the unsubscibe will happen when component is destroyed, so only when user will navigate on another page, it will stay alive as long as the page is displayed which is useless, that's what I mean

Comment: If you want to unsubscribe it as soon as you do not need it, you can use operators such as first(), take(2) or takeUntil(suitableNotifier) based on your specific need. You do not need to wait till page navigation.